# When is it bad idea to count incrementally in urls?

Tags: security, query-string

I have a webpage where I want to display a video and three thumbnails for a watch next video.

Right now I have it set up so that it takes in a parameter from the query string and that determines which files are retrieved to display on the page.

So the url would be something like organization.org/video/?v=5. Which would tell it do display video number 5 and watch next panels for videos 4, 3, and 2.

I do this all in javascript because the video files are specifically named, so that they can all be found with just their number. (e.g. video5.mp4)

So obviously this allows a user of the page to figure out exactly how I do this and access all of the video and thumbnail files that I have set up for display. I also know that youtube uses random base-64 numbers to id their videos, but youtube has a complicated structure with unlisted videos and other factors, whereas mine is pretty simple.

If all of the files that use the format shown are available on the webpage to anyone anyway is there a compelling reason to switch to a slightly more obscure way of displaying videos?

Comment: If all the urls are public anyway, you're safe. Just make sure you have nice-looking 404 pages set up for videos that don't exist (i.e. "?v=abc",  "?v=-1", or "?v=999999999") and you're good.

Answer (score 1):

If all videos are public, then you can use simple numbers which are incremented (predictable). The problem that Youtube mitigated is named "insecure direct object references" and you can read about it [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).